# Highest ID with Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a postgresql database with two columns and I want to display the latest entry with Spring boot. The latest entry is the row with the highest ID. I did it like this but it didn´t work:

```
@Entity
public class Messwerte implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private double temperatur;

    public Messwerte() {
    }
//getters, setters, etc.

@Repository
public interface MesswertRepository extends JpaRepository<Messwerte, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT max(id) from messwerte")
  public List<Messwerte> getMaxID(Long id); 
}



@Service
@Transactional
public class MesswerteService
{
  @Autowired
  private MesswertRepository messwerteRepository;
  
  public List<Messwerte> getMaxId(Long id)
  {
    return messwerteRepository.getMaxID(id); 
  }
}



@GetMapping("/maxId")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Messwerte>> getMaxId(@PathVariable Long id) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getMaxId(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

[image]
[image]

I am new in Spring boot so please help me!

Comment: The `Bad Request` you are showing is most likely not related to the DB-Query. I would assume Spring is not happy about the missing `@PathVariable Long id` in your `@GetMapping`. Why do you even need this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because your query returns the `max(id)` and not the row. This means that the result of the query will be a `Long` and not `Messwerte`.

You are also expecting a parameter that you are not using.

One way to rewrite the query is using a subquery:

```java
@Query("select m from Messwerte m where m.id = (select max(id) from Messwerte)")
public Messwerte getMaxID();
```

Note that, because this query returns at most one result, I've changed the return value to `Messwerte`. But you can still return `List<Messwerte>`, if you prefer.

This should also work:

```java
@Query("select m from Messwerte m where m.id = (select max(id) from Messwerte)")
public Optional<Messwerte> getMaxID();
```

Comment: I would suggest deleting the parameter `Long id`. I don't think it is needed. Also I would suggest returning an `Optional<Messwerte>` to cover the case of an empty DB-Table.

Comment: Right, I've just copied and pasted it quickly. Is it necessary to return Optional? I would expect this to work even if the result is null

Comment: I am not sure, if it is strictly necessary. But it is good practice especially because other methods of the repository will also return `Optional` such as `findOne`.